# How to use isNaN and charAt in in Angular 7 typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am not able to use `charAt(index)` and `isNaN()`. It says:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'isNaN'.

```
fuctiontocheckfirstchar(control: AbstractControl) {
  const val: string = control.value;

  if (!isNaN(val.charAt(0))) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return { 'pass': true };
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try window.isNaN?

Comment: Try Number.isNaN()

Comment: typo: `fuction` -> `function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Number.isNaN() instead of isNaN()

anf for val.charAt() make sure that

> val 
>   is string type.

Comment: In the code the OP shows `val` is defined as `const val: string`, so it should be a `string`,  or is there anything else the OP has to do to ensure that `val` of type string?